# ios - background thread calling a property and returning nil

Tags: ios

I am very new to IOS programing.
I've created a class, that uses a NSURLConnection to download data async.

I use a delegate that's sent across and in turn updates my father class. Part of updating the father class includes calling a UIView that has been saved in a local property.

Here are some code examples of what I mean:

**myClass:**

```
@synthesize myView = _myView;

-(void) loadMetaData
{
    if(self.isMetadataLoaded)
    {
        [self.myView metadataLoaded];
    }
    else {
        [_htmlLinter summarizeUrl:self.originalLink];
    }
}

-(void) urlSummarized:(NSDictionary*)data
{
    self.productTitle = [data objectForKey:@"title"];
    self.productDescription = [data objectForKey:@"description"];
    self.provider = [data objectForKey:@"provider_name"];
    self.isMetadataLoaded= true;
    [self.myView metadataLoaded];
}
```

**htmlLinter:**

```
-(void)summarizeUrl:(NSString*)url
{
    NSURL* u = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:request];
    ...
    ...
    ...
    //removed a lot of logic that doesn't seem to be relevant 
    //Important to notice, that this is being called on a different thread though:
    [self embedlyDidLoad:result];
}

-(void) embedlyDidLoad:(id)result
{
    NSDictionary* properties = (NSDictionary*)result;
    [_facilitator urlSummarized:properties];
}
```

The strange thing is this:
myClass doesn't remember what self.myView is when accessed through another thread.
This line the problematic one : [self.myView metadataLoaded];

it returns a valid pointer when called initially in loadMetaData,
but when I call it on another thread in urlSummarized, it is nil.

What can be causing that?

Comment: Its not possible to tell what the connection between these bits of code and your mentioned use of NSURLConnection is. BTW you are not accessing things in different threads when you use NSURLConnection (you have probably read that NSURLConnection spawns a thread of your behalf, which is why you are saying that?)